# array push in javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to create an associative array of dates and style. I am expecting an array like

```
{   
   dates: [{day: 1, month: 12, year: 2021}, {day: 15, month: 12, year: 2021}],
   styleClass: 'test'
},
```

And my code is

```
var markedDates = [];
markedDates['dates'].push('day: 1, month: 12, year: 2021');
markedDates['dates'].push('day: 15, month: 12, year: 2021');
markedDates['styleClass'].push('test');
console.log(markedDates);
```

which returns error

Comment: `styleClass` also has to be an array: `styleClass: ['test']`

Comment: for pushing, you need an array. [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: markedDates should be defined as {}. And why you're not just copying the source in the top of your question confuses me.

Comment: And you're currently pushing strings, not objects.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and, if needed, use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: You probably come from PHP background - please remember that in JavaScript, and most other languages, there is no such thing as "associative array". This is just an object.

Comment: try defining markedDates as `var markedDates = {dates:[],styleClass:[]};` at least it would fix your error. And you can start restructuring your array/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that you should consider -

1. Make an object that needs to be pushed into the bigger array. Eg: `markedDate` in the below code.
2. Assigning a string should be directly with an equal to operator and no need to push it, like in an array
3. Initialize the internal field `dates` as an array before pushing into it first

```js
var markedDates = [];
var markedDate = {};
markedDate['dates'] = [];
markedDate['dates'].push({day: 1, month: 12, year: 2021});
markedDate['dates'].push({day: 15, month: 12, year: 2021});
markedDate['styleClass'] = 'test';
markedDates.push(markedDate);
console.log(markedDates);
```

Comment: Don't encourage using `markedDate['dates']` - the author confused this syntax with PHP's associative arrays. In JavaScript, it's the same as `markedDate.dates` and using square brackets syntax with hardcoded values makes zero sense and - for a dessert - is slower.

Comment: @RoboRobok Maybe it's a dynamic field and never good to assume if not mentioned otherwise :)

Comment: `['dates']` is a dynamic field? Please just admit a mistake and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1: `markedDates` has been defined as an array (`[]`). To define it as an object (which is what you have as your expected output), use `{}`. (No such thing as an 'associative array' in JavaScript; arrays use `0`, `1`, etc. as indexes. Objects use `0`, `1`, `key`, `another_key` as indexes [or keys, more accurately].)

Problem 2: You haven't defined the `dates` array within `markedDates` which will cause a reference error.

Problem 3: You are pushing strings to the array instead of objects. This won't error, but won't produce the intended output.

Problem 4: You're trying to use `styleClass` as an array - it's just a string property within the `markedDates`.

To fix your code in the line-by-line manner (keeping similarity to your original code):

```js
var markedDates = {};

markedDates.dates = [];
markedDates.dates.push({day: 1, month: 12, year: 2021});
markedDates.dates.push({day: 15, month: 12, year: 2021});
markedDates.styleClass = "test";

console.log(markedDates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

But if you've got your expected output statically defined at the top, you can just assign that directly to the variable as such:

```js
var markedDates = {
  dates: [{ day: 1, month: 12, year: 2021 }, { day: 15, month: 12, year: 2021 }],
  styleClass: 'test'
};

console.log(markedDates);
```